# How to display a bootstrap range from the one and how to show the value in the input field?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, range

I am using [bootstrap 5 range](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/range/) . I am getting some issues

1. Why dot displaying in the center of the line? I added the min value of 1
2. How can I display the value of the range in the input field?
3. How to change the background color or linear gradient of the line?

```css
.customRange {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.customRange:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.customRange::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="w-50 mx-auto">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><label>Range</label>
    <div><input type="text" name="" value="">%</div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" class="form-range customRange" min="1" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>100</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `value="1"` to intialize your thumb at `1` . Then , write change event on range input and assign value using `$(this).val()` to your other inputs . I am not sure about 3rd issue because in that docs its written `supports "filling" their track.., we do not currently support it...`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("input[type=range]").on("change input", function() {
  $("[name=values]").val($(this).val())//assign value..
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="w-50 mx-auto">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><label>Range</label>
    <div><input type="text" name="values" value="">%</div>
  </div>
  <!--use value=1-->
  <input type="range" class="form-range customRange" value="1" min="1" max="100">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>100</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Yes, It's working. about the color let me keep the same for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = document.getElementById("LoanTermSlider");
    var span = document.getElementById("slider-label");
    var marginValue = parseInt(slider.value) * 5 - 4;
    var attrValue = "margin-left:" + marginValue + '%;';
    span.setAttribute('style', attrValue);
    var _yrsTxt = "yrs.";
    if (parseInt(slider.value) < 10) {
      _yrsTxt = "yr.";
    }
    span.innerHTML = slider.value + " " + _yrsTxt;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      marginValue = parseInt(this.value) * 5 - 4;
      if (parseInt(this.value) == 20) {
        marginValue -= 6;

        if (screen.width < 993) {
          marginValue -= 6;
        }
      }
      span.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:' + marginValue + '%;');
      _yrsTxt = "yrs.";
      if (parseInt(this.value) < 10) {
        _yrsTxt = "yr.";
      }
      span.innerHTML = this.value + " " + _yrsTxt;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
._yrs {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #297195;
  display: inline-block;
}

#LoanTermSlider {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <span class="_yrs" id="slider-label"></span>
  <input type="range" class="form-range" min="1" max="20" step="1" id="LoanTermSlider" name="LoanTermSlider">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="max-amount f-16 font-weight-normal darkGray-color text-right mt-1">1 yr.</span>
    <span class="max-amount f-16 font-weight-normal darkGray-color text-right mt-1">20 yrs.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.